# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

Tags: yammer

We are getting this error sometimes or making continues REST API request to Yammer.

XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got the reason for this error. When you continuously request or you hit the Yammer REST API limit mentioned in https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/ then usually this error comes.

so solution we followed is smartly handle your code by making request as per Yammer like putting some caching or limiting controls to page.

I hope this will solve your issue.