# Yammer REST Api making different calls from different pages

Tags: javascript, rest, yammer

I have a simple piece of code that finds the groups available to a user on Yammer using the Yammer JavaScript api and it looks a little like this:

```
yam.platform.request({
 url: "groups.json?mine=1",
 method: "GET",
 success: function (data) {
     callback(data);
 },
 error: function (error) {
     console.log(error);
 },
```

});

The call is carefully wrapped so it only ever happens once per page request, but it appears to succeed or fail on a totally arbitrary basis. The response either looks like this:

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 26 Nov 2014 17:32:42 GMT
P3P:CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Server:nginx
Status:429
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Date:1417023162896
X-Runtime:0.032459
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

or like this:

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://my-access-origin.sharepoint.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:content-type, network_id, authorization, x-csrf-token, www-authenticate, x-xss-protection, ETag
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 27 Nov 2014 12:17:38 GMT
ETag:"123a45b67cd89ef01234ab45cd67ef"
P3P:CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Server:nginx
Status:200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Date:1417090658344
X-Robots-Tag:none
X-Runtime:0.066098
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

In the former case, I see an error message in the Network panel of my development tools that looks like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1&&_=123456. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://my-access-origin.sharepoint.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 429.

This doesn't make sense for a couple of reasons - first that the request is exactly the same in both cases and secondly that I am getting "429 Too Many Requests" as the status code, but with an explicit report that the Access-Control-Allow_origin header should be set. Which it never is in my requests, but it does appear to be on the successful responses.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you web url in Yammer registered app's "Javascript Origins"

if still the same issue then it could be:

This is related to Yammer rest API limit, more over to this 429 error 
https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/

Please refer my answer on this post
[XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907935/xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x80070005-access-is-denied)

Comment: I also facing similar issue due to access controll origin. some set of APIs are only availing at www.yammer.com not in `api.yammer.com`, SDK is using `api.yammer.com` where `groups.json` API have issue. No too many request I have sent still showing this issue. PS - there is no documentation on this API in developer docs. My Q&A Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305722/yammer-api-issue-get-groups-showing-error